# Display related fields from another table on a Microsoft Access form

Tags: ms-access

I have two tables, Job and Client.  Job has a column, ClientId, that is keyed to Client.Id.  On my Job form I want to display a "Client" dropdownlist that displays Client.ClientName, but when I change its value it is linked with the appropriate Client record. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you wish to use a combo that stores the Client ID in the jobs table but displays the client name? If so, you can use the wizard to add the combobox and it will guide you through the steps.

Basically, what you need is:

```
Row Source Type: Table/Query
Row Source: SELECT ClientID, ClientName FROM ClientsTable ORDER BY ClientName
Bound Column: 1
Column Widths: 0;2cm  '' 0 means that the client ID is hidden from the user
Column Count: 2
Control Source: JobClientID  '' This is the name of the Job field to hold Client ID
```